# fetch json object containing 3 arrays with ajax call and pass arrays to javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I have a page that creates the following output:

```
<script>
  var JSONObject = { "groups":['1210103','1210103','1210103','1210405'],
                     "prices":['279,00','399,00','628,00','129,00'],
                     "titles":['','','','']
                    }; 
</script>
```

This page is called by an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({url:plink,success: function(result) { }
```

I now need to recieve the json arrays and pass them to ordinary javascript arrays.
How do I do that?

I have tried with:

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
mygroups = result.groups;
myprices = result.prices;
mylabels = result.titles;
```

Comment: there is some problem with the syntax of your ajax call..

Comment: A script that contains an object literal is not a [JSON](http://json.org) file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your page so that it *just* produces JSON:

```
{"groups":["1210103","1210103","1210103","1210405"],
 "prices":["279,00","399,00","628,00","129,00"],
 "titles":["","","",""]
}
```

Note that in JSON, you **must** use `"`, not `'`, for quoting strings.

Have it return a `Content-Type` header of `application/json`. If for some reason you can't set the correct `Content-Type` header on the response, you can force jQuery to treat the response as JSON by adding `dataType: 'json'` to your `ajax` call, but it's best to use the correct `content-Type`.

Then in your `ajax` call's `success` callback, `result` will *already* be a deserialized object with three properties (`groups`, `prices`, `titles`), which will be JavaScript arrays you can work with.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ixojuc/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ixojuc/1/edit)

---

You've said in the comments below that the page is a full HTML page with the embedded `script` tag and you have no control over it other than the contents of the `script` tag, because of the CMS you're using.

I **strongly** suggest moving to a more flexible CMS.

Until/unless you can do that, you can simply receive the page as text and then extract the JSON. Change your `script` tag to something like this:

```
<script>
var JSONObject = /*XXX_JSONSTART_XXX*/{"groups":["1210103","1210103","1210103","1210405"],
 "prices":["279,00","399,00","628,00","129,00"],
 "titles":["","","",""]
}/*XXX_JSONEND_XXX*/;
</script>
```

Note the markers. Then you can extract the JSON between the markers, and use `$.parseJSON` on it. Example:

```
(function($) {

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://jsbin.com/ecolok/1",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {
      var startMarker = "/*XXX_JSONSTART_XXX*/";
      var endMarker   = "/*XXX_JSONEND_XXX*/";
      var start, end;

      start = result.indexOf(startMarker);
      if (start === -1) {
        display("Start marker missing");
      }
      else {
        start += startMarker.length;
        end = result.indexOf(endMarker, start);
        if (end === -1) {
          display("End marker missing");
        }
        else {
          result = $.parseJSON(result.substring(start, end));
          display("result.groups.length = " + result.groups.length);
          display("result.prices.length = " + result.prices.length);
          display("result.titles.length = " + result.titles.length);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ixojuc/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ixojuc/2/edit)

Comment: I have updated so " is used. The page I receive is a complete html page - including the <script>. I can edit the output within the <script></script>. The ajax is updated to: $.ajax({url:plink,dataType:'json',success: function(result) {

Comment: @MortenRepsdorphHusfeldt: If the page you're loading is a complete HTML page, it seems odd you're trying to load just the bit within the `script` tag. Why are you trying to load the full page rather than create one with just the data on it?

Comment: I'm locked into a webshop cms system with its limits. Unfortunately I cannot avoid the page structure

Comment: @MortenRepsdorphHusfeldt: That's a pretty flawed CMS. See the updated answer.